# How to call function after last function call in PHP with fluent interface?

Tags: php, fluent

I've been puzzled by this for a while,

How can I execute a function after the last function call in PHP with fluent interface?

For example, if I have a class instanced and chained like this:

```
$myclass->function1()->function2()->function3();
```

If there a way to execute a piece of code after the last function used in the fluent interface? It could after be function1(), function2() or function3()...

I need to keep this line as is:

```
$myclass->function1()->function2()->function3();
```

I can't use:

```
$myclass->function1()->function2()->function3()->afterFunctions();
```

nor

```
$myclass->function1()->function2()->function3().""; // to trigger __toString()
```

and there could be any number of chained functions called, i.e.

```
$myclass->function1()->function2();
```

I thought maybe I could use the `__destroy()` magic function, but that won't do as there could be multiple calls to the class within the same scope, i.e.

```
function test() {
    $myclass = new Class1();
    $myclass->function1()->function2()->function3();

    $myclass2 = new Class1();
    $myclass2->function2()->function3()->function1();
}
```

There might be a magic function I am unaware of that could help with a final function to [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) chained kind of classes.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: When you are asking a question that is bizzarre even to yourself, you should always ask about initial problem. Not "I want" but "I need my code to provide such and such result".

Comment: No, there is nothing that can intuit that you're done making calls against an object and simply wish that something else would happen. If you want something to happen, then you need to write a method that does it, and then invoke it. "Fluent interface" is not a thing inherent to PHP or OOP, it's just a style of writing and invoking code that some people seem to like.

Comment: I think I'll have no choice but to refactor my code to get the fluid interface with the last function called differently, sucks that there's no way for this tho :(